# Overlay Vector Layer on Raster Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, overlay

How can I overlay a Vector Layer on a Raster Layer and assign NoData Values on the Raster where the Vector Layer does not cover the Raster Layer?

(preferable with ArcGIS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing can be accomplished using [Extract by Mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002n000000).  For example, the image on the left shows raster imagery with a polygon overlay.  The image to the right shows the result of the extract by mask operation.  By default, ArcGIS assigns NoData pixels as no-color.  For display purposes, I reassigned the NoData pixel color from no-color to black via: Layer Properties > Symbology > Display NoData as "Black".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. reclassify raster and use nodata in reclassify
2. convert reclassified raster to vector ( name =  x)
3. clip the vector layer with x : the result is Nodata in vector layer ( vector y)
4. Erase vector layer with vector y : the result is vector layer without Nodata location.

Comment: I am sorry. Either I misunderstand your steps or I was not specific enough in my question. What I want in the end is a Raster Layer only having values for the area covered by the vector layer.